# jQuery UI Datepicker - return values

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I am following a tutorial about jQuery UI, and, although it works, I am trying to find the explanation in the jquery UI Datepicker documentation but I can't find what I am looking for.

To disable weekends, the tutorial creates a function:

```
   function onBeforeShowDay(theDate) {
        //day 0 is sunday, 6 is saturday
        if(theDate.getDay() == 0 || theDate.getDay() == 6) {
            return [false, "weekend", "Weekends disabled"];
        }
        return [true, ""];
    }
```

And then it gets called on beforeShowDay:

```
 $("#datepick1").datepicker({
           firstDay: 1,
           showButtonPanel: true,
           currentText: "Today",
           closeText: "close",
           beforeShowDay: onBeforeShowDay,
           numberOfMonths: 1,
           constrainInput: true

       });
```

The return  value is an array with true/false, a css class you might want (it can be empty), and the title you want for those weekends. Where am I suppose to find this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the API (http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay)

**beforeShowDay**

A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:

- [0]: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable
- [1]: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default   presentation
- [2]: an optional popup tooltip for this date

The function is called
   for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.